Console.log shows I have the data, but I am failing in rendering the value in jsx
I have a model set up like this
const chapterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: String, required: true },
});


const studyTipSchema = new mongoose.Schema([
  { tip1: String },
  { tip2: String },
  { tip3: String },
]);


const storySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  chapters: [chapterSchema],
  studyTips: [studyTipSchema],
});


const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  stories: [storySchema],
});


The idea is to dynamically render three buttons; each button displaying its own studyTip when clicked.
I have successfully brought over the data from MongoDB and passed it down to my StudyTips.jsx component. I have things to this point.

The image shows that I have successfully dynamically created three buttons; one button for each studyTip. Clicking on each button shows that I am getting the index for each specific studyTip in the array. Great so far. That code follows.
function StudyTips({
  category,
  currentStoryIndex,
  currentStudyTipIndex,
  setCurrentStudyTipIndex,
  close,
}) {
  if (!category || category.length === 0) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }


  const currentCategory = category[currentStoryIndex];


  const handleStudyTipClick = (index) => {
    setCurrentStudyTipIndex(index);
    console.log("Current study tip",   currentCategory.studyTips[index]);
  };


  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex-container">
        <div className="study-tip-container">
          <div className="study-tip-content">{currentStudyTipIndex}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="study-tip-btn-set">
          {currentCategory.studyTips.map((studyTip, index) => (
            <button
              key={studyTip._id}
              className={
                index === currentStudyTipIndex
                  ? "study-tip-btn active"
                  : "study-tip-btn"
              }
              onClick={() => handleStudyTipClick(index)}
            >
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


What I am needing to do is to display the studyTip text that is at index 0, 1, and 2, not simply the index value.
In my handleStudyTipClick() function, I log the following
console.log("Current study tip", currentCategory.studyTips[index]);

and see that I am successfully getting the text value for each button as desired, but every attempt I make to get the text value into my jsx code is failing. I always get an error saying that the index is not defined. I see it is an issue with scope, but I have been unable to figure this out. A little help?

You can use the useMemo hook
const studyTip = React.useMemo(() => 
    index >= 0 ? currentCategory.studyTips[index] : '', [index]
);
...
<div className="study-tip-content">{studyTip}</div>

Or you can use the useState hook
const [studyTip, setStudyTip] = React.useState(
    currentCategory.studyTips.length ?
    currentCategory.studyTips[0] : ''
);

const handleStudyTipClick = (index) => {
    setCurrentStudyTipIndex(index);
    setStudyTip(currentCategory.studyTips[index]);
};

...
<div className="study-tip-content">{studyTip}</div>


Unfortunately, the errors continue. Using both useMemo and useState returns "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {tip1, _id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." There is a stackoverflow response to that error. I am trying to work with it now... Thank you for your response, though.

Sorry, that's my bad I didn't notice index isn't defined outside the scope. If you add a new state for const [studyIndex, setStudyIndex] = React.useState(0) and then change the studyTip memo to watch the studyIndex that might work.
